# Cannot set property 'image' of undefined

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to make a Create Routeand this is my code:

```
    router.post("/", middleware.isAdmin, upload.single('image'), function(req,res){
        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
            req.flash('error', err.message);
            return res.redirect('back');
          }
          // add cloudinary url for the image to the meal object under image property
          req.body.meal.image = result.secure_url;
          // add image's public_id to meal object
          req.body.meal.imageId = result.public_id;
          // add author to meal
          req.body.meal.author = {
            id: req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username
          }
          Meal.create(req.body.meal, function(err, meal) {
            if (err) {
              req.flash('error', err.message);
              return res.redirect('back');
            }
            res.redirect('/meals/' + meal.id);
          });
        });
    });
```

And in my model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var mealSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    imageId: String,
    description: String,
    price: String,
    author:{
        id:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Meal", mealSchema);
```

When I try to add a new meal the server disconnects and I this error:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'image' of undefined
at /Users/talalsy/Desktop/Capital_Sandwich/routes/meals.js:44:27
at /Users/talalsy/Desktop/Capital_Sandwich/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js:1073:12
at IncomingMessage. (/Users/talalsy/Desktop/Capital_Sandwich/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:402:9)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

What might be the problem?

Comment: Add `console.log(req.body.meal);` at the beginning of your post handler. Should be `undefined`, which is bad. How do you call/test your route?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're not passing meal object in the request or you're misspelling it or some issue like but the error is sure that you're not getting the meal in req.body.